# How to log the content of a store or model using console.log

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJS 4.1.3.  I have the following statement to log the content of the store on the console (Firebug/Chrome)

```
console.log('Stored Record : ' + grid.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData);
```

I get the output

```
Stored Record : [object Object]
```

The content is displayed correct on a grid.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are concatenating the text `'Stored Record : '` with your object by using the plus sign `+`, that makes firebug try to convert the object into a string.

When firebug converts an object into a string it looks like `[object Object]`. Instead you should just print the object by itself:

```
console.log(grid.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData);
```

If want to print all the records in the store after they have been loaded this would work better:

```
grid.getStore().each(function(record) {
    console.log(record);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Geronimo.  I am accepting this answer as it has the explanation of the cause.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
console.log('Stored Record : ' , grid.getStore().getProxy().getReader().rawData);
```

refer : [Outputting_text_to_the_console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console#Outputting_text_to_the_console)